# How to get the LAST INSERT ID when using python-asyncio databases

Tags: sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, starlette

I'm trying to persist an object in the database using the following stack: [Starlette](https://www.starlette.io/), [SQLArchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) and [Databases](https://www.encode.io/databases/).

How can I get the LAST INSERT ID?

```py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String)
```

```py
async def create_user(request: Request) -> JSONResponse:
    data = await request.json()
    query = User.__table__.insert().values(name=data["username"])
    await database.execute(query)

    # I need the LAST INSERT ID here
```

Comment: just assign the result to a variable like: last_insert_id = await database.execute(query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not expecting the solution to be that simple. I couldn't find it in the documentation.

It seems that the result of the query will return the LAST INSERT ID if there is one:

```py
    last_insert_id = await database.execute(query)
```